# Problem in displaying h1 tag inside a function in Reactjs

Tags: html, reactjs

I am a begineer in Reactjs. I can't figure out why on pressing the button "Hii" is not displaying in the browser please help me out

```
import React from 'react'

  const Letsee=()=>{
   return(
    <>
     <h1>Hii</h1>
    {console.log('Hii')}
   </>
  )
}

function Test1() {
 return (
   <>
   <button onClick={Letsee}>Press</button>
   </>
  )
}

export default Test1
```

Answer (score 0):

An `onClick` listener invokes the function when the button is clicked but it doesn’t do anything with the return value.

So in your example `Letsee` gets called and returns some JSX that nobody is waiting for.

If you want to display something new after the click you might want to look at `useState`.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function Test1() {
  [showH1, setShowH1] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      { showH1 && <h1>hi</h1> }
      <button onClick={() => setShowH1(true)}>Press</button>
    </>
  )
}
```